# Python function with specific parameters as inputs, exceptions

Tags: python, list, if-statement, input, parameters

I have a function  **mean_univ** with three parameters and I want that it raises Errors when one of the below given conditions are met,

1. x is not a list
2. x contains other values than int or float, e.g. strings
3. if the string you input as method is not "mean" or "tmean"
4. if alpha isn't between 0 and 1

When I define for example `x=[1,2,4,10,12]`
my code doesn't raise the Exception (3.) and I don't know how to implement the 2. and 4.
Thanks.

```
def mean_univ(x, method, alpha=-1):
  if type(x) == list:
    if method == mean:
      return mean(x)
    elif method ==tmean:
      return tmean(x,alpha)
    else:
      raise Exception("no available method")
  else:
    raise Exception("no list")



def mean(x):
    return print(float(sum(x)) / max(len(x), 1))

def tmean(x, alpha):
  s = sorted(x)
  a = round(alpha * len(x))
  trimmed_list = s[a:-a]
  if len(trimmed_list) == 0:
    return
  trimmed_ave = sum(trimmed_list)/len(trimmed_list)
  return trimmed_ave
```

Comment: _and I don’t know how to implement the 2 and 4._ What’s the problem, which part are you struggling with?

Comment: The function should work if x is a list and have only int or float values. But I don't know how the "if statement" need to look if x is a list but contains a string. For this case I want an exception

Comment: Right, I got that part, I was hoping for something more specific. Have you tried breaking down the problem, writing pseudocode, etc. ?

Comment: Can you clarify your problems? You obviously know how to check types and values already. As for 2: ``mean`` and ``tmean`` will throw an error anyways if the elements aren't numbers. As for 3: ``method`` *isn't* supposed to be a string, your function expects another function. As for 4: Checking whether a value is smaller/greater than a value is pretty basic, what precisely are you struggling with here?

Comment: sorry I try to specify it: For example: 1. step: User will input a list x=[1,2,3,4,5,"red"]. Then he will run the function mean_univ(x,mean) and an error occurs. Yes an error occurs but I want an specific exception to tell the user that he need to adjust the list. For 3: 1. step: User will input a list x=[1,2,3,4,5,]. Then he will run the function mean_univ(x,Hmean) and an error occurs that Hmean is not defined. here I want an specific exception to tell the user that method he tries to run not exists. For 4: I think I got a solution for that point.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, I see the following issue:

```
def mean_univ(x, method, alpha=-1):
  if type(x) == list:
    if method == mean:
      return mean(x)
    elif method ==tmean:
      return tmean(x,alpha)
    else:
      return print("no available method")
  else:
    raise Exception("no list")
```

It is coded to say that if `x` is a list, then look at the `method` to check if it is within specifications.  So as long as a `list` is entered for `x` then it won't go to the `raise Exception("no list")` piece of the code. You also need to enclose "mean" and "tmean" in quotes. I made some changes to your code and it seems to work:

**My Code**

```
def mean_univ(x, method, alpha=-1):
    if not isinstance(x, list):
        raise Exception("no list")

    if method == "mean":
        return mean(x)
    elif method == "tmean":
        return tmean(x,alpha)
    else:
        return print("no available method")
```

So `mean_univ([1,2,4,10,12] , method="mean")` gives `5.8`

`mean_univ(3 , method="mean")` throws an `Exception: no list`

`mean_univ([1,2,3] , method="other")` gives `no available method`

Not sure what you mean by the fourth point where you say:

> if alpha isn't between 0 and 1

Because your default value of alpha is -1. If you want to add a value check for `alpha` then you could add the following lines nested in the `mean_univ`

```
if not 0 <= alpha <= 1:
        return "Invalid alpha value"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've came up with the following solution:

```
def mean_univ(x, method, alpha=-1):
    if not isinstance(x, list):
        raise ValueError("x is not list")

    if any(not isinstance(item, int) and not isinstance(item, float) for item in x):
        raise ValueError("x does not contains proper values")

    if method != "mean" and method != "tmean":
        raise ValueError("Incorrect method")

    if alpha <= 0 or alpha >= 1:
        raise ValueError("Incorrect alpha")

    if method == "mean":
        return mean(x)
    elif method =="tmean":
      return tmean(x,alpha)
    else:
      return print("no available method")
```